# How to clear TMP folder using PHP (PHP Sessions)

Tags: php, session

I have a folder named "tmp" in my webserver, it contains 237 files. 
Title is something like this `sess_1at4ka9r77f0f4n4ijldv561d1` and it contains data something like this `FBRLH_state|s:32:"183047584cfac9ca4353c21535caa39d";`

All files were last modified on `06/08/2018` (today). But the thing is

I think it contain PHP session data.

I use this code to create php sessions

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400 * 90);

session_start();
```

Now this is a bit confusing. only 12 people visited my website today. But why there are 237 session files?

Did i wrote some bad code? How can I minimize `tmp` folder size?

Comment: So, yes, those are session files. We don't know whether you wrote bad code. They will get cleaned out eventually by PHP based on the gc lifetime. You can `rm` them yourself if you want. … What exactly do you want to know from us?

Comment: Why there are 273 files actually? Only 12 people visited my website, and session gets started only when someone login.

Comment: So, can i just delete them manually by logging in my server?

Comment: We don't know why there are 273. Yes, you can delete them.

Comment: Don't worry about them, they are automatically removed by PHP if needed and and the system, when it get low on space.
It's a temp folder.
If you want to remove them yourself, I suggest you write in `session_destroy()`.

Comment: `session_destory()` remove session for all users or  only the guy who runs the code? I think only for the guy who runs the code right?

Comment: yes. that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the code you've shared states whether your session files will be eventually removed or not. That code only says that, *if* garbage collection is triggered as a result of this script's execution, only files older than that will be removed.

Whether current script will launch session clean-up and how often it'll happen is determined by the runtime values of these directives:

- [session.gc_probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability)
- [session.gc_divisor](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor)

(All this, assuming you haven't fiddled with [session.save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler) to implement a custom mechanism, in which case your custom code should take care of handling data removal properly.)

As about the 237 files, I presume it's the default shared directory where all PHP scripts store sessions by default—but of course it's just a guess (I don't even know their modification time).